# Configure Robolectric in build.gradle

Tags: gradle, robolectric, robolectric-gradle-plugin

Can anybody explain me how to make robolectric to work with gradle in android studio? I've tried many times with different configurations but nothing works. 
Maybe this is a simple question but I now have no idea how to do this. I use android studio 1.1.0 and gradle 2.2.1

Comment: There are many samples. Where do you get stuck?  http://robolectric.org/getting-started/ and https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-samples and https://github.com/nenick/AndroidStudioAndRobolectric

Comment: in second variant I receive Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebugTest'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
 C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output D:\...\app\build\intermediates\dex\test\debug --input-list=...\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\test\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
 2
Output:
 UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
 com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/maven/artifact/Artifact;

Comment: what do you call second variant? this kind of errors should be reported in the github project as issue

Comment: sorry, I mean github.com/nenick/AndroidStudioAndRobolectric

Comment: Which commands do you use? Sorry I don't get this error. Please help me to reproduce it. A coworker has windows too but also don't get this error. Do you try with original code or do you have changes?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is hardly simple. Integrating Robolectric based testing and unit-testing in general isn't trivial - it's something Google has left behind when releasing the early versions of Android Studio, and is currently a work in progress. Fortunately, it seems that upgrading to Android Studio v1.2 might do the trick for you now, if you follow this post: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/triumph-android-studio-1-2-sneaks-in-full-testing-support/